# want to see you back at work

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

*I know he only wants the best for you. So do I. **I want to see you back at work,** and...*

Is this the most idiomatic way to say this, or would I need "I want to see you come/get/return to work"?

I should mention that I'm his colleague and only wants to see him back at our workplace, I'm not his boss who might be impatient for him to come back and take part in the work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> I want to see you back at work

is perfectly idiomatic.

If you would like to make sure that he does not take it as you being impatient (even though that is highly unlikely) you could use:

> I **would like** to see you back at work

That is what I would personally use, and I think that would be slightly more common in AmE.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see you back at work

That is 100% correct and idiomatic.